# Метод map для массива

Tags: javascript, map

Подскажите как дополнить функцию так, чтобы она возвращала массив имён пользователей из массива объектов в параметре users. Для перебора параметра users используется метод map().

const getUserNames = users => {};

СПАСИБО!!!
Помогли. Смутили скобки {}

Comment: `=> users.map(user => user.name)`

Comment: Какой язык вы используете?

Comment: ой, блин, точно

Comment: Исправьте оформление https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

`const getUserNames = users => users.map(user => user.name);`

Answer (score 0):

Если массив передан сразу:

```
    const users = [
  {
    name: "Moore Hensley",
    email: "moorehensley@indexia.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ["ipsum", "lorem"],
    gender: "male",
    age: 37,
  },
  {
    name: "Sharlene Bush",
    email: "sharlenebush@tubesys.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Briana Decker", "Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    skills: ["tempor", "mollit", "commodo", "veniam", "laborum"],
    gender: "female",
    age: 34,
  },
  {
    name: "Ross Vazquez",
    email: "rossvazquez@xinware.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Marilyn Mcintosh", "Padilla Garrison", "Naomi Buckner"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    skills: ["nulla", "anim", "proident", "ipsum", "elit"],
    gender: "male",
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    name: "Elma Head",
    email: "elmahead@omatom.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Aisha Tran"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    skills: ["adipisicing", "irure", "velit"],
    gender: "female",
    age: 21,
  },
  {
    name: "Carey Barr",
    email: "careybarr@nurali.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Jordan Sampson", "Eddie Strong"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    skills: ["ex", "culpa", "nostrud"],
    gender: "male",
    age: 27,
  },
  {
    name: "Blackburn Dotson",
    email: "blackburndotson@furnigeer.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Jacklyn Lucas", "Linda Chapman"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    skills: ["non", "amet", "ipsum"],
    gender: "male",
    age: 38,
  },
  {
    name: "Sheree Anthony",
    email: "shereeanthony@kog.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Briana Decker"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    skills: ["lorem", "veniam", "culpa"],
    gender: "female",
    age: 39,
  },    
];
```

то решение в 2 вариантах:

```
const getUserNames = users.map(user => user.name);
const getUserNames = users.flatMap(user => user.name);
```